# Regular Chaparral comes out bold, bold Chaparral comes out regular. Why?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

Chaparral.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Chaparral Pro}
\begin{document}

Hamburgefonstiv Regular

\textbf{Hamburgefonstiv Bold}

\end{document}
```

Chaparral.log: http://pastebin.com/wNKG07h0

Result:

[image: Result]

Adobe [Caslon/Garamond Premier/Minion/Myriad] Pro come out correctly with equivalent syntax. The .otfs are all present in C:\Windows\Fonts. All came with CS3. LuaTeX beta-0.76.0-2013061707 (rev 4627).

Is this a bug I should report to http://tracker.luatex.org/, or is it an issue with Chaparral, or is it working correctly in a way I don't understand?

**Edit:** Nevermind. I just found http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=572

Comment: What happens if you are more explicit? E.g.: `\setmainfont[UprightFont = ChaparralPro-Regular.otf, BoldFont = ChaparralPro-Bold.otf]{Chaparral Pro}`.  (Note: I don't have the fonts and I don't use Windows; but your `.log` clearly shows that it can find these files....)

Comment: It does work if I'm more explicit. Even the name "Chaparral Pro Regular" is interpreted correctly, but naming the files works as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a (reported) bug in LuaTeX.